# Evaluate a prefix expression using stacks

Tags: java, math, data-structures, stack, discrete-mathematics

I have to evaluate a prefix expression using stacks, I did it but I don't understand why the code doesn't work properly, it marks 2 bugs when I compile the code, they are:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at evaluationprefix.EvaluationPreFix.EvaluationPrefix(EvaluationPreFix.java:56)
    at evaluationprefix.EvaluationPreFix.main(EvaluationPreFix.java:25)

```
public class EvaluationPreFix {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack st = new Stack();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter the size of expression");
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        System.out.println("enter an element");
        String element = sc.nextLine();
        st.push(element);
    }

    int r = EvaluationPrefix(st); //marks an Error here
    System.out.println("Result: " + r);

}

public static int EvaluationPrefix(Stack st) {
    Stack st2 = new Stack();

    while (!st.isEmpty()) {
        Object e = st.pop();
        if (e.equals('+')) {
            st2.push((Integer) st2.pop() + (Integer) st2.pop());
        } else if (e.equals('-')) {
            st2.push((Integer) st2.pop() - (Integer) st2.pop());
        } else if (e.equals('*')) {
            st2.push((Integer) st2.pop() * (Integer) st2.pop());
        } else if (e.equals('/')) {
            st2.push((Integer) st2.pop() / (Integer) st2.pop());
        } else {
            st2.push(e);
        } 
    }
    return (Integer) st2.pop();//marks an error here
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes made:

- In the **main** method, changed the stack, **st**,  to `String` type.
- In the **EvaluationPrefix** method,

  - changed the parameter stack to `String` type.
  - changed the stack, **st2**, to `Integer` type.
  - changed the arithmetical operators within `equals` to `String`.

Here you go,

```
public class EvaluationPreFix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //1. parameterized with String
        Stack<String> st = new Stack();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter the size of expression");
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter an element");
            String element = sc.nextLine();
            st.push(element);
        }

        int r = EvaluationPrefix(st); //marks an Error here
        System.out.println("Result: " + r);

    }

    //2. parameterized with String
    public static int EvaluationPrefix(Stack<String> st) {
        //3. parameterized with Integer
        Stack<Integer> st2 = new Stack();

        while (!st.isEmpty()) {
            String e = st.pop();
            //4. arithmetic sign comparison to string instead 
            //of character
            if (e.equals("+")) {
                st2.push(st2.pop() + st2.pop());
            } else if (e.equals("-")) {
               st2.push(st2.pop() - st2.pop());
            } else if (e.equals("*")) {
               st2.push(st2.pop() * st2.pop());
            } else if (e.equals("/")) {
               st2.push(st2.pop() / st2.pop());
            } else {
               st2.push(Integer.valueOf(e));
            }
        }

        return st2.pop();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think wherever you use `st.push` it should be `st2.push` (when checking the operators)

Comment: No. Only the last on goes to `st2`. Try it out, e.g., 2 3 + will give you result of 5. You have to push back in the same stack.

Comment: but it is prefix, so it should be + 2 3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are talking about [java.util.stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) - this is just a Collection storing what you push into it, and you are using it as **raw type**.

```
Stack st = new Stack();
```

That means you can push objects of any type onto this stack. It seems that you only want to store `Integers` - tell the compiler about that by using generics.

```
Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();
```

This will tell you that the problem is wherever you try to convert `e` to an Ìnteger`by casting, because in your case, the values of`e`are the`String`s you pused into`st`in`main()`.

You should also replace the declaration of `st` in `main` with

```
Stack<String> st = new Stack<>();
```

and the method declaration to

```
public static int EvaluationPrefix(Stack<String> st)
```

to highlight the problem.

When you have a `String` and want to convert it to an `Integer`, you need to parse it, for example using [Integer.parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-). But you need to be aware that this method will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the `String` is not a number. You will have to handle this exception, for example by catching it and printing a helpful error message.

Comment: right, so now the problem would be here `st2.push(e);` because `e` is `String` and `st2` is only for integers, so how could I fix it?

Comment: I can't make a casting